# Why is word ladder not used?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is the tag for [word-ladder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-ladder), the connecting of two words e.g [LEAD into GOLD](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50113/turn-lead-into-gold?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, it is rarely used: 6 questions are tagged as such, although there have been many puzzles that are actually word ladders but don't have the tag, such as the one I linked.

They are usually tagged with wordplay, letters or something similar but not as the actual word ladder puzzle that it is.

Should questions be retagged or something? Or does it not matter all that much?

Comment: @boboquack I think it's an appropriate tag since it's about a specific type of puzzle which is frequently seen.. I think it's just that people don't realize it's what it is

Comment: @boboquack You're misunderstanding the question. There are *many* puzzles of this type on PSE, but only 6 where people have bothered to add the tag already.

Comment: ^ That is what I'm getting at.. If you go into wordplay or letters you can find word-ladder puzzles all over the place in some form or another

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, let's use this tag more.

There's a valid and clearly defined type of puzzle here, so it does merit a special tag. And there *is* a tag already; people just haven't been using it properly. Let's fix that.

Going forward, **let's make sure all new word ladder puzzles are tagged with [word-ladder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-ladder).** Older questions which need the tag might be harder to find, but we can retag them as we come across them. Standard disclaimers apply: don't go and edit twenty of them at once and push all the new questions off the front page of the site.

I'm [Doing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/50113/revisions) My [Bit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/50125/revisions)!

Comment: So change them but not all at once.. And then hopefully some people come across this meta post and realize to use the tag